# JBoss Deployment Info

Tags: spring, deployment, jboss, config

More of a standard practice questions:

1. Is there any difference in deploying an app as EAR vs WAR? How do you decide? (I know WAR is just a web application may or may not have Java EE features like messaging)
2. Lets say I have a Spring MVC application stack with Hibernate (MySQL DB), should this be deployed as a War or EAR?
3. When do we need to worry about JBoss deployment descriptors, if I am not using EJBs. (Just Spring MVC). Lets assume I have JMS as well. Do we need to configure/update/create any other JBoss related config files?
4. When we package our application EAR/WAR, it include EVERYTHING that we need for our app. Is there a scenario where we need to keep some config / xml files outside of this archive in a specified JBoss folder?
5. Is it common practice to deploy directly from Eclipse or better to use Ant, etc? Advantage / Disadvantage?

Obviously, I am a newbie :-). Trying to understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.
This is not always an easy decision, but for beginners and for small projects I would say it's nearly always a WAR. The reason for using an EAR is mainly to isolate a business layer from a UI/Web layer. See this question for more details: [How can one isolate logical layers of an Java EE application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13962293/how-can-one-isolate-logical-layers-of-an-java-ee-application)

2.
I might be mistaken but I think that Spring people typically prefer WARs.

3.
JBoss (vendor) specific deployment descriptors are mostly needed to configure so-called "administered objects" and security. Sometimes they can be used for extra features that are not covered by the Java EE specification (e.g. setting the web root for a WAR). Administered objects are typically data sources (connection to a database) and JMS destinations (queues and topics).

In the traditional Java EE approach these have to be created as far away from the code as possible, which typically means a system admin would create them inside the target AS using some kind of GUI or admin console. In this setup, you as developer would throw a WAR with "unresolved dependencies" over the wall, and a system admin (or "deployer") would then spend days figuring out what those unresolved dependencies should be.

If the communication is relatively good between developers and deployers, the WAR or EAR might be thrown over the wall together with a readme-file, that at least gives some insight into which resources are needed. Depending on the organization the development team might not get any access or feedback about how those "unresolved dependencies" have been resolved. E.g. a data source with a max of 5 connections may have been created, but this may be insufficient if some code does say 10 parallel queries. Without the development team knowing the exact data source configuration, some classes of runtime problems and performance issues may be relatively hard to solve.

To mitigate these problems, some vendors, for some artifacts, offer the developer to create those "unresolved dependencies" instead using proprietary deployment descriptors which are then embedded in the WAR or EAR. For simple local JMS destinations this is then in most cases the end of it, but for data sources there is a little bit more to it. Namely, there has to be a mechanism to switch between data sources for different stages such as Dev, Beta, QA, Production etc. Additionally, it's rarely a good idea to have production passwords in the source code.

If you have a simple app that you want to try out locally, stages and production passwords are not a concern. If you deploy for a (large) company it is.

In Java EE 6 you can define a data source using a standard descriptor (web.xml, ejb-jar.xml or application.xml), and in Java EE 7 you can do the same for JMS destinations. There is no standard way to configure those based on stage, but there is a glimmer of hope that Java EE 8 will address this (see e.g. [JAVAEE_SPEC-19](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVAEE_SPEC-19)). Vendors are not universally happy with those standardized methods, and their main documentation will almost always extensibly tell you how to do those things using their proprietary tools and descriptors, and if you're lucky as a small note tell you there's a standardized way (and then sometimes downplay that or scare you by saying it's not recommended to be used in production).

4.
See answer to 3 mostly. One option to solve the problem of how to switch between stages and keep production passwords out of the WAR/EAR, is to have the full definition of said data source inside the AS (inside JBoss in your case). Every AS installation is tied to a specific server in this setup. If data sources need to be updated, removed or new ones added, you have to communicate with your operations team (if any). As said, depending on your organization this can be anything between trivial and practically impossible.

5.
When developing you most often use your IDE to do a deployment. For production you would never do that. For production you may build with Ant (or Maven) and deploy via something like Jenkins, or e.g Chef.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check here : [.war vs .ear file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594667/war-vs-ear-file)
2. If you read the preceeding response, you'd guess that "WAR" it is.
3. Deployment descriptor are needed to manage the modules of JBoss, if you don't have any conflict or don't need any tweaking, you won't need any deployment descriptor.
4. You may need to play with some JBoss file if you want to add modules to JBoss, or configure  datasources, etc. Read the JBoss documentation for more info.
5. You can deploy from eclipse during your development phase, but as your other environments (qualification, production, test, etc) should be separeted from your developing one and that they won't have any eclipse installed on them, you should get used to manage your server from the command line and drop your war's in the right directories.

It's a short answer, but I hope it will help.

Read JBoss documentation for more info.

Comment: +1 for providing better documents for review. @Kevin Rave - typically, you'd use an EAR to deploy multiple WARs. This allows you to package all of your deployables to one project while still configuring each WAR independently.